# Remote ssh command using sudo

Tags: ssh, sudo

I have this command:

```
ssh user1@192.168.242.16 'sudo -u oracle fgrep ...'
```

can someone explain me how this command works ? I just know that someone is connecting to remote computer as user1 and want to run some command as oracle. He can do this ? Need user1 some privileges and why when I run this command I need to set password of user1 and not oracle ?

thx

Answer (score 2):

With sudo you can run stuff as any user you like.

This command will work if user1 is added to sudoers with NOPASSWD which means user1 can perform commands with sudo and is not required to enter his password when doing so

Answer (score 0):

ok this command is two parts:

```
ssh user1@192.168.242.16
```

connects to the remote box and logs in as User 'user1'

the second command starts with 'sudo', a utility that allows a user to temporarily exercise root authority. the ability to run sudo is a right granted to a user, so a user without sudo capability will not be able to run sudo at all.

Sudo prompts a user to input their own password. this ensures that the user really wants to run the job as root and that they are the authorized user for that account. that way, only a sudo-capable user can take root, and they are forced to prove that they are who the system thinks they are.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a *"chained"* command:

1. **authenticate** against the remote system as *user1*
2. invoke on the remote system a command with **effective user** *oracle*

Important is to understand **why** this is used:

1. For security reasons some accounts are not accessible via *ssh*.
   This can be done by configuration (see below).
2. The remote user account has simply no password or has no usable entry in `.ssh/autorized_keys`.

#### Note - deny ssh access for specific accoutns

In the most default configurations the *root* account is blocked for *ssh*.
This is normally done in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with the option:

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

In addition you can specify there the options 
`DenyUsers`, `AllowUsers`, `DenyGroups`, and finally `AllowGroups`.

For detailed informations see `man sshd_config`.